# Unable to find my CV source file

Tags: templates, cv

One year ago I made my CV using a LaTeX template I found somewhere, maybe editing it a little bit (but nothing major).

Then bad things happened to my computer, I thought I had backups of everything but... It turns out that, while I had my pdf CV (from many emails I sent), the .tex source file is nowhere to be found.

I find myself unable to find it anywhere (I even used Google History but nope), so I am posting here hoping someone knows this template or something close to that.

[image]

(to upload this picture I edited the pdf to stay anonymous. It is a horrible procedure and I do not want to go through it everytime I want to update my CV)

I would also appreciate suggestions on other similar-looking CV templates, as it is not mandatory for it to look exactly like the old one.

Comment: I think this link may help you: https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/cv#.WNkDuoc0NLM. The third in the page seems to be very similar to yours.

Comment: See also the Professional CV here: https://it.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume.

Comment: Thank you, they are both great alternatives! I still hope someone recognizes the precise one though :)

Comment: There is also Plasmati Graduate CV here: https://www.latextemplates.com/cat/curricula-vitae

Comment: I managed to edit (quite a lot) the first one you linked and got something really close to what I was looking for. I will put it here tonight or tomorrow! Thank you

Comment: Good... and don't forget to make a backup :)

Comment: Ah, I still don't know how this could have happened. I have backups of my classwork from primary school but this particular tex file managed to slip through the cracks D:

Comment: Sometimes the PDF has the raw LaTeX code embedded in it, I think.